# Cannot send DM to all member of the discord server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I get errors when I am trying to send DM to all members from the same server.

```js
guild.members.cache.forEach(async (member) => {
    try {
        if (!member.user.bot) {
            await member.createDM();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(member.user.username + " dm closed.", e);
    }
});
```

This isn't working. Nothing happens. I only have a bot and a member in my server.

I don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cache is empty. Try fetching the members. Something like this:

```js
guild.members.fetch().then(async (members) => {
    members.forEach(async (member) => {
        //...code goes here...
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually nothing happens when I do it without `cache`. When I use my code I see in the logs that the discordjs do recognize all my server members `memberCount : 3`. However, I don't know why the loop only takes in account the bot and not the members.

Comment: try catching the error see whats actually happening `guild.members.fetch().catch(error=>console.log(error));`

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. Discords disabled intents by default and I was required to enable them manually.